# get private key in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, signing, saml-2.0

We are deployed on google app engine and we have a requirement to sign a request that we make to external identity provider(saml based).I read the appidentity documentation and have been able to retrieve the public key.I know that every app deployed on google app engine has its own private key. I need reference to that private key as java.security.PrivateKey;so that i can sign my request.
Another reason is i am using openSAML for creating SAML Requests and for signing my requests, I need to set the privateKey in a Credential Object.

Anyone out there who can help me with my problem ? Is this even doable in google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

There's is no way to download the private key. However, the method [signForApp](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/appidentity/AppIdentityService.html#signForApp%28byte%5B%5D%29) is provided in the [AppIdentityService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/). This method allows you to sign an arbitrary byte array.